# Highcharts.chart is not a function?

Tags: javascript

I am getting the json data but its not showing in jsp page. In console **Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'navigator' of undefined exporting.js:9** and **export-data.js:10 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'document' of undefined** and      highcharts.chart is not a function

I have copy the highchart js file in my local path

```
<script src="${resourceUrl}/js/highchart/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="${resourceUrl}/js/highchart/exporting.js"></script>
<script src="${resourceUrl}/js/highchart/export-data.js"></script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.getJSON( "http://localhost:8080/mandatoryCheck/generate2", function(data) {
        var chart = new Highcharts.chart('cvsMandCheckGraph', {
            chart: {
                type: 'column'
            },
            title: {
                text: 'Top 5 Mandatory Checks Fail'
            },
            subtitle: {
                text: ''
            },
            xAxis: {
                categories: " ",
                crosshair: true
            },
            yAxis: {
                min: 0,
                title: {
                    text: ''
                }
            },
            tooltip: {
                headerFormat: '<span style="font-size:10px">{point.key}</span><table>',
                pointFormat: '<tr><td style="color:{series.color};padding:0">{series.name}: </td>' +
                    '<td style="padding:0"><b>{point.y:.1f} mm</b></td></tr>',
                footerFormat: '</table>',
                shared: true,
                useHTML: true
            }, 
            plotOptions: {
                column: {
                    pointPadding: 0.2,
                    borderWidth: 0
                }
            },
                shadow: true
            },*/
            series: [{
                colorByPoint: true,
                data: data
            }]
        });
    });
});

$(document).ready(function(){
    $.getJSON( "http://localhost:8080/fieldModification/generate", function(data) {
        var chart = new Highcharts.chart('cvsFieldModiChart', {
            chart: {
                plotBackgroundColor: null,
                plotBorderWidth: null,
                plotShadow: false,
                type: 'pie'
            },
            title: {
                text: ''
            },
            legend: {
                itemStyle: {
                    fontSize: '10px'    
                }
            },
            subtitle: {
                text: 'Top 5 Field Modifications'
            },
            xAxis: {
                categories: []
            },
            tooltip: {

            },
            plotOptions: {
                pie: {
                    allowPointSelect: true,
                    cursor: 'pointer',

                    dataLabels: {           
                        enabled: true,
                        format: '<b>{}</b><br>{point.percentage:.1f} %',
                        distance: -30,
                        color: '#fff',
                        style: {
                            textOutline: false ,
                            fontSize: 9,
                        },
                        filter: {
                            property: 'percentage',
                            operator: '>',
                            value: 4
                        }               
                    },
                    showInLegend: true
                }
            },
            series: [{
                name: '',
                style: { fontFamily: '\'Lato\', sans-serif', lineHeight: '18px', fontSize: '17px' },
                colorByPoint: true,
                data: data
            }]
        });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can make use of below CDN link.It will make sure the Highchart.chart is available.
If you are using jQuery make sure that jQuery CDN link should provide before Highchart Link

```js
console.log(Highcharts.chart)
```

```html
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
```

Comment: I am using inside the head <script type="text/javascript" src="${resourceUrl}/js/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script> and inside the body i am using <script src="${resourceUrl}/js/highchart/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="${resourceUrl}/js/highchart/exporting.js"></script>
<script src="${resourceUrl}/js/highchart/export-data.js"></script>